# using QList<T> in a connect( ) call

Tags: qt

I am writing my first application in Qt4, basically using the books of Blanchette/Summerfield andSams 24 hours, and a lot of Qt search on internet.
my actual call is:

```
connect( thumbNailView, 
     SIGNAL(leftClicked(QListWidgetItem *)),
     leftKeypointList,
      SLOT(openItem(QListWidgetItem *)));
```

which gives the following error: 
    "no matching function for call to DAPPMainWindowWidget::connect(DAPPListWidget*&, const char [32], DAPPKeypointList*&, const char [29])"

I also connected this signal to another object which works flawless:

```
connect( thumbNailView,
     SIGNAL(leftClicked(QListWidgetItem *)),
     leftImage,
     SLOT(openItem(QListWidgetItem *)));
```

Both leftImage and leftKeypointList are pointers to objects to a standard QWidget and and a custom object DAPPKeypointList : public QList with DAPPKeypoint holding index and position 
of the keypoint.

My idea is that I cannot simply pass a pointer to QList sort of object the same way as I do a pointer to a standard Qwidget.

below follow:

in my DAPP.h

```
  private:
            DAPPKeypointList * leftKeypointList;
            DAPPKeypointList * rightKeypointList;
```

and classes:

```
class   DAPPKeypoint {
    public:
                    DAPPKeypoint();
                    ~DAPPKeypoint();

            QPoint  getKeypointPos();
            void    setKeypointPos(QPoint);
            int     getKeypointIndex();
            void    setKeypointIndex(int);

    private:
            QPoint  keypointPos;
            int     keypointIndex;
};




class DAPPKeypointList : public QList<DAPPKeypoint> {
    Q_OBJECT
    public:         DAPPKeypointList();
                    ~DAPPKeypointList();


    private slots:
            void    openItem(QListWidgetItem *);
};
```

in my cpp files:

DAPPKeypoint.cpp

```
#include "DAPP.h"

            DAPPKeypoint::DAPPKeypoint(){}

            DAPPKeypoint::~DAPPKeypoint(){}

    QPoint  DAPPKeypoint::getKeypointPos(){ return keypointPos; }

    void    DAPPKeypoint::setKeypointPos(QPoint kpPos){ keypointPos = kpPos; }

    int     DAPPKeypoint::getKeypointIndex(){ return keypointIndex; }

    void    DAPPKeypoint::setKeypointIndex(int kpIndex){ keypointIndex = kpIndex; }
```

DAPPKeypointList.cpp: (for the moment just a template ...)

```
#include "DAPP.h"

            DAPPKeypointList::DAPPKeypointList(){}

            DAPPKeypointList::~DAPPKeypointList(){}

    void    DAPPKeypointList:: openItem(QListWidgetItem *) {}
```

And DAPPMainWindowWidget.cpp :

Parts that are relevant (if you need more, let me know, but I think this is sufficient to have an idea of the problem):

```
                    leftKeypointList = new DAPPKeypointList;
                    rightKeypointList = new DAPPKeypointList;


                    leftImage       = new DAPPImageWidget(leftImageLabel);


            connect(thumbNailView,SIGNAL(leftClicked(QListWidgetItem *)) ,leftKeypointList  ,SLOT(openItem(QListWidgetItem *)));

            connect(thumbNailView,SIGNAL(leftClicked(QListWidgetItem *)) ,leftImage         ,SLOT(openItem(QListWidgetItem *)));
```

Comment: Got some smarter, I think at least, it seems to have to do with QList not inheriting QObject ... method connect() is part of QObject therefore QList cannot connect is what I understand now, because receiver and sender both must have access to connect().

Comment: Ah, I see hyde gave me that hint already!

Comment: I think problem is solved with the conclusion that both sender and receiver must be basically of QObject ... I'll find a work around.

Comment: don’t derive from containers, make them a member.